# Returning a Container

Tags: c++, c++11, return-value

I'm playing around with performance for a while and I'm still not sure, what's the best solution.

I read a lot of articles and also did performance tests my self:

For example let's take a Container(e.g vector of strings) with a lot of elements. Copying it would very costly.
Therefore returning it as reference would be a good solution.

```
//Vector
vector<string>& GetVector()
{
    return vecy;
}
```

I've tested this solution on Windows 8.1 VS2013 Express (in a loop ofc) & standard release build (02 optimization)
vs. return by value.

The difference was huge, and returing a reference was very fast.

Today I've done the same test on a MAC OS-X using XCode which uses -0s optimization for standard release build.

Here, return by value was much faster than returning it by reference (seems like, optimization worked better).

My first question is: which would be the best solution now? Or is there no best solution and I just have to adjust my code to the compiler?

I know another solution would be to use the c++11 move, but what if I want to keep the vector on my object, but also where i call the GetVector(); (but no copy).

2) Question:

What do you thing about following code

```
vector<string> vec;

vector<string>* GetVector()
{
 return &vec
}
```

call function:

```
vector<string>* vec2 = GetVector();
```

(Let's say i know exactly how long the object lives, which returns the pointer to my vector)

Using this method with a pointer was the fastest in my performance tests, but is it a good solution?
Would it better to use smart_pointers, but how?
Or are there any other solutions?

Comment: Q2 - It is NOT a good solution because you will screw up memory management in long run. If your `vector<string> vec` is not static/global, how is the address valid when you want to use it somewhere else? You should have used `std::shared_ptr<>`. Q1 - I believe there will be lots of mixed opinions about this as you have touched a very common and yet, sensitive area in C/C++ memory management. I'll wait to see what others answer.

Comment: Could you show your benchmark code (and result) ?

Comment: I've just added 50 strings to a vector, and called vector = GetVector() about 30000000 in a loop. Tests have shown that with  LLVM C++11 support it's faster to use return by value, and with GNU C++, it's faster to return by reference, I also recognized that return by reference using GNU C++ is 3x much faster than LLVM C++11 return by value. IS C++11 slower at returning values in general or is it just the compiler?

Answer (score 1):

For getter, simply return by (`const`) reference.

To build a vector (since C++11), return by value (and at worst you have a move).

Comment: but why is it so slow in VS2013?
How about parameters.
void function(vector<string>& vec){...} should be references also avoided here?

Answer (score 0):

In C++11 if it is not a shared object you can take advantage of move constructor by simply doing:

```
vector<string> GetVector()
{ 
   // do something
   return vec;
}
```

Comment: so return by value automatically uses the move constructor?, this was exactly what I did in VS2013 on Windows, it was very slow. but it was fast on OS-X. As far as I know both supported c++11

Comment: yes that is automatic, you can force it by doing std::move(vec);

Comment: but that means, my vector won't be available in the current object any more

Comment: Rather than employing a move, it is said that compilers use Return Value Optimization. This employs no copy and no move, but instead the object is directly constructed where the function is invoked. See [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Return_value_optimization) for example.

Comment: @Sleicreider just to be clear, it will only use the move constructor automatically if `vec` is a local variable that will go out of scope at the end of the function, otherwise it will create a copy.

Comment: but this only works for return values right? not for parameters.
what would be the best way to get a Container through a parameter? just `func(vector<string>& vec){myVector = vec //copy}` ? or using a smart pointer?

Comment: in another stackoverflow post, I've read that this only works for local variables

Answer (score 0):

You cannot compare benchmark speed of how compilers on different platforms are handling STL containers. Handling STL containers through code is optimized on compiler level, and it will you give different results.

It is quite possible that std::map will act totally different than std::vector and be faster for example on Windows platform.

If you need to get fastest methods on both platforms, I am afraid you will need to use preprocessor commands.