# RVO & returning a container

Tags: c++, performance, c++11

As far as I know in C++11 with RVO it's better to return things by value.
I did some performance tests where I just call a GetVector() method in a loop(300000000 loops) and write the value on a vector in another class(Vecto should be still available in both classes): Function Call:

```
vector<string> myvec = myObjec.GetVec();
```

Let's take a container with about 50 std::strings:

Compiler LLVM C++11 support on OS-X

```
vector<string> vec;
vector<string> GetVector()
{
 return vec;
}
```

With C++11 support, return by value is faster than return by reference.

Compiler GNU C++

With this compiler return by reference is faster than return by value, and return by reference is also much faster than return by value with C++11 LLVM.

Question 1: is GNU C++ just faster here or C++11 slower in general at returning values, because of RVO?

My next question:

I've tested the same example with pointers, which was the fastest method in my tests:

```
vector<string> vec;
vector<string>* GetVector()
{
 return &vec;
}
```

Call the function:

```
vector<vec>* vec;
vec = myObj.GetVector();
```

This example is very fast, but I heard it would screw up memory management in long run, but why?

Third Question:

If using raw points is a bad example I would use at least smart_pointers, they are somehow not as fast as raw pointers(think this is because of shared_ptr) but still much faster than just return by value, but in some articles I've read that it's a bad example and just mess up my code. But why would it be bad to use smart pointers?

Comment: RVO is not limited to c++11.

Comment: "and return by reference is also much faster than return by value with C++11 LLVM." – a few lines before that, you assert the exact opposite ("Compiler LLVM C++11 support on OS-X", "With C++11 support, return by value is faster than return by reference."). I can't make sense of any of your question, its grammar is very bad and it's very incoherent.

Comment: Didn't you ask [the same question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/26937109/596781) just a short while ago?

Comment: Benchmarking meaningfully is surprisingly difficult - you should post code so we can verify you've done it properly.  From your opinions in this and the other question Kerrek links, it seems very likely you're making some *huge* mistakes in your benchmarks....

Comment: Where's the RVO here? RVO is for returning locals. I see no way for the compiler or a human or a squid to avoid a copy in this code.

Comment: RVO is kinda new to me, In another stackoverflow topic I was told it would also apply in this code.

Comment: But why was return by value faster than return by reference, using the LLVM compiler in x-code?

Comment: @Sleicreider See TonyD's comment.

Answer (score 3):

There's no RVO involved in this code:

```
vector<string> vec;
vector<string> GetVector()
{
    return vec;
}
```

because `vec` is still available, so you can modify `vec` and return value of `GetVector()` independently. Therefore the compiler has to create a copy of `vec`.

More formally, C++11/14 standard section `12.8/31` says:

> (...) This elision of copy/move operations, called *copy elision*, is permitted in the following circumstances (which may be combined to eliminate multiple copies):
>   — in a `return` statement in a function with a class return type, when the expression is the name of a non-volatile **automatic object** (other than a function or catch-clause parameter) with the same cv-unqualified type as the function return type, the copy/move operation can be omitted by constructing the automatic object directly into the function’s return value
>   (...)
>   — when a **temporary class object** that has not been bound to a reference (12.2) would be copied/moved
>   to a class object with the same cv-unqualified type, the copy/move operation can be omitted by
>   constructing the temporary object directly into the target of the omitted copy/move

C++98 standard says basically the same (except for moving) in `12.8/15`.

This means that RVO applies only if you return a local variable or a temporary object.

Comment: hmm, I've heard, that it won't create a copy, but instead the object is directly constructed where the function is invoked

Comment: @Sleicreider read my clarification

Comment: what would be the best&fastest solution to return a container then?

Comment: @Sleicreider depends on your needs.

Comment: @Sleicreider: Jarod42 already told you in your previous question.

Comment: just a fast way to get a vector from another class and read its values. I don't want to use a std::move, because it should be still available in the other class and a copy would be too expensive. My Solution would be return by reference or pointer/smartpointer

Comment: ok, so return by reference is a good choice for such a getter method, but why are smart pointers bad in this case?

Comment: Because when the client pointer goes out of scope, the original vector (which wasn't allocated with `new`) would be released via `delete`, causing undefined behavior.

Comment: @Sleicreider, Using a pointer is roughly equivalent to using a reference but a reference is slightly less error prone and you don't need to be able to return null in this case. Smart pointers are normally only returned from functions when you are passing ownership. In the case of a getter the object retains ownership so smart pointers are a bad idea.

Comment: I'm asking, because when Call the getter method somewhere else
`vector<string> = obj.GetVector(); //copy`
I still have a copy, but with a pointer, I can directly access the vector

Comment: @Sleicreider, if `obj.GetVector()` returns a reference you have to store it in a reference `vector<string>& vec = obj.GetVector();` if you want to avoid a copy.

Comment: @Chris Drew, and this will cause no problems?

Comment: @Sleicreider Well, it is a reference to a `vector` inside `obj` so you need to ensure that the thing it refers to is still alive when you try and use it. But as long as you practice RAII that is usually quite easy to arrange.

Comment: @Sleicreider In certain circumstances you might want to return a `weak_ptr` or `shared_ptr` from a getter but you need to ensure that the original object is allocated dynamically and stored in a `shared_ptr` and in your case it is not, see FredOverflow's comment. But in most cases this is not necessary.

Comment: but why would is a pointer like this so bad?(compared to the reference) isn't it as dangerous as using a reference?:
`vector<string>& GetVec(){return vec};

vector<string> *vec = &GetVec();`